How to determine for each competition the associated sport using Betfair API
I want to save the sports and competitions in my database. In the competitions table, I have the sport_id foreign key.
I know that in the 'SportsAPING/v1.0/listCompetitions' method I can send all sport IDs in a single request but, In response I don't have the associated sport ID from the Betfair API. I tried to make the request for each sport from my database but, it gave me this error:
{
"token": "",
"product": "7bsIh7LEHJ3GSzsy",
"status": "FAIL",
"error": "TEMPORARY_BAN_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS"
}

How do I call that method with all sports IDs and get the associated sport?
Thanks!
